# How do I add objects to an Array of type Created class?

Tags: java

I am creating a Card program which has multiple classes (A CARD Class, DECK, HAND, etc)
For my Deck class I have to create an Array of Cards but I am not sure how

Class CARD has two Enum variables Which is Suit and Rank and I have to add the Cards to the array. 
The fixed size of Array has to be 52.
P.S - I am not allowed to use ArrayLists

Any tips on how to go about this?

Comment: Where is the code? What is stopping you from generating an array?

Comment: See [Oracle Java Tutorials - Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: You can have multiple enums in a class.

Comment: Nothing was stopping me from generating an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of cards then add elements using the Card constructor:

```
CARD[] cards = new CARD[52];
cards[i] = new Card(...);
```